# How to use MSBuild to build an existing .NET 4 project for .NET 5?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

Is it possible to msbuild a project that was created for .NET 4.x against the .NET 5 SDK without upgrading the project in VS?

I have a .NET 4.7 library project that I compile for .NET 4.x using msbuild (and this issue is easily reproducible by creating a "Class Library (.NET Framework)" project for .NET 4.7).

I want to build it for .NET 5, so I tried

```
dotnet msbuild /property:TargetFrameworkVersion=net5.0 /property:TargetFrameworkIdentifier=.NETCoreApp



Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(8,31): error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)" that evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition "('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' != '.NETCoreApp' OR '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' < '3.0') AND [H:\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(8,31): error MSB4086:                                          ('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' != '.NETStandard' OR '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' < '2.1')". [H:\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj]
```

That seems to want `$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)` so I tried

```
dotnet msbuild /property:TargetFrameworkVersion=net5.0 /property:TargetFrameworkIdentifier=.NETCoreApp  /property:_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV=5.0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(84,5): error MSB4184: The expression "[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPathToStandardLibraries(.NETCoreApp, net5.0, '', '', '', '')" cannot be evaluated. Input string was not in a correct format. [H:\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj]
```

PS: I did also try comparing a pure .NET 5 library project against a .NET 4 one and based on that tried this

```
dotnet msbuild /property:TargetFramework=net5.0 /property:TargetFrameworkIdentifier=.NETCoreApp  /property:_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV=5.0 /property:TargetFrameworkVersion=5.0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1180,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [H:\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj]
```

Comment: This website - what's the -1 for?  I put in the effort, I think the question is reasonable.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/ You have to port the projects manually, and no shortcut is there. Put your efforts in the right direction please. There are already tons of questions here on .NET Framework to .NET Core migration (and .NET 5 is not different).

Comment: @LexLi I see - I appear to have made an assumption based on the name ".NET 5" that is was more framework than core.  It was only butting up against this problem and the responses that I realise that, and that porting to core is relevant in moving from .NET 4 to 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NET 5` is the new release version of **Net Core** rather than **Net Framework**.

[See this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five):

[image]

**And** `NET 5` is for new-sdk style project while net framework 4.7 project in your side is non-sdk style project.

**So** you can not use a new-sdk style project's property for a non-sdk style project. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format).

**Also**, new-sdk style projects use `TargetFramework` while non-sdk style project uses `TargetFrameworkVersion`. And `.NET 5` should be used with `TargetFramework` but your non-sdk project does not identify it.

**Solution**

So you should change your net framework project from `non-sdk` into `new-sdk`.

You could create a new net core project and then change its xxx.csproj file into:

```
<TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
```

And then migrate your old project's content into the new one which means that this project is a `new-sdk` style project with net framework.

See [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) and also [this document](http://hermit.no/moving-to-sdk-style-projects-and-package-references-in-visual-studio-part-2/).

**Then**, you can use

`dotnet msbuild /property:TargetFramework=net5.0`